# Working off mapped network drive throws "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." exception

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have a few Visual Studio 2012 C# projects that use MySQL. I added the references to the MySQL .dll file long ago.

I work off a mapped drive and had to configure permissions with .Net Framework 2.0 Configuration so that everything would work. This worked fine.

...up until two days ago (6/4/18) when my Windows 10 computer did an update.

Now, when developing off the network my sql queries throw this exception:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

If I copy the project folder to my local computer, the exception goes away and the project runs fine.

What do I need to do to get these projects working again while on the mapped drive?

(I use source control but the mapped drive is a work drive that gets backed up each night which is what I want)

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to find a solution to fix this but I did find a work around which was to go to the project's Properties and under Build change the Output a local directory. This way my project is on the server and allows debugging (locally).